# Monitor maximum memory consumption in Node.js process

Tags: javascript, node.js, profiling

I'm looking for a cross-platform way to reliably monitor maximum memory  consumption in Node.js process, regardless of whether there are leaks or not.

The processes in my case are both real applications and synthetic tests.

I would expect it to work like

```
process.on('exit', () => {
  console.log('Max memory consumption: ' + ...);
});
```

It was possible to trace memory consumption somehow with `node --trace_gc ...`, but this resulted in output that is hard to read (and probably hard to analyze programmatically). Also, GC didn't occur when a script ended too fast, even if RAM usage was substantial.

From what I have seen on the subject, usually `memwatch` is suggested for that, like:

```
require('memwatch-next').on('stats', stats => {
  console.log('Max memory consumption: ' + stats.max);
});
```

But in my case it triggered only when GC already happened or didn't trigger at all, so it was useless for determining RAM consumption peaks.

I would prefer to avoid GUI tools like `node-inspector` if possible.

Can this maximum memory consumption be reliably retrieved as a number from the application itself or CLI alone, cross-platform?

Comment: Is my solution as crossplatform as you need it to be?

Comment: @EMX In fact, yes, thanks, it looks a thing that I need. pidusage seems to be crossplatform. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Great, hope it solves your question the way you needed :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use Node.js `process.memoryUsage()` method to get memory usage stat:

> The process.memoryUsage() method returns an object describing the memory usage of the Node.js process measured in bytes.

It returns the object of the following format:

```
{
  rss: 4935680,       // Resident Set Size
  heapTotal: 1826816, // Total Size of the Heap
  heapUsed: 650472,   // Heap actually Used
  external: 49879     // memory usage of C++ objects bound to JavaScript objects managed by V8
}
```

To get the maximum memory consumption in Node.js process, `process.nextTick` method could be used. `process.nextTick()` method adds the callback to the *next tick queue*. Once the current turn of the event loop turn runs to completion, all callbacks currently in the next tick queue will be called.

```
let _maxMemoryConsumption = 0;
let _dtOfMaxMemoryConsumption;

process.nextTick(() => {
  let memUsage = process.memoryUsage();
  if (memUsage.rss > _maxMemoryConsumption) {
    _maxMemoryConsumption = memUsage.rss;
    _dtOfMaxMemoryConsumption = new Date();
  }
});

process.on('exit', () => {
  console.log(`Max memory consumption: ${_maxMemoryConsumption} at ${_dtOfMaxMemoryConsumption}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. There are typos in variable names. Also, it likely should run on same tick and on exit as well to get full coverage.

Comment: @estus I fixed the variable names, thanks for mentioning this. What about adding calculation in `exit` callback, I don't think that it's necessary (of course if you don't want create a huge object there:)). This event usually used to _cleanup_ memory.

Comment: Yes, adding the calculation to exit *in addition to nextTick* works pretty well. But the problem I've encountered is that process.nextTick should be set up recursively in order to track it in async scripts, but the fact that there is incomplete interval prevents it from calling `exit` when script ends. I solved it with `setInterval(calculate, 10).unref(); process.on('exit', calculate); process.on('exit', () => {...})`.

Comment: @alexmac do you know how to add npms to nodejs that are written in C&C++?

Answer (score 7):

If you try to benchmark the process from within itself, you will have distorted memory usage values. (if you want more information about this, just comment)

---

This is a little (**crossplatform**) tool I coded for checking the memory usage of another process, it spawns an independent process and watches every 100ms for memory usage in order to find the highest peak, outputs everytime a new peak is found and stops once child has ended.

It uses [`pidusage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pidusage) which is a crossplatform process ( cpu % and ) **memory** usage of a PID

Allows customization of the spawn (arguments to be passed along with the spawn) *[could be updated for command line usage]*

It will also work with any node binary name, since it will reuse the one  used to start this tool.

```
'use strict'
const UI = {};  var ñ = "    "
const pusage = require('pidusage');
//:Setup the 'cmd' array to be the file and arguments to be used
const ANALYSIS = {cmd:['child.js']}
ANALYSIS.child = require('child_process').spawn(
 process.argv[0], // reuse to work with the same binary name used to run this (node|nodejs|...)
 ANALYSIS.cmd,   // array with filePath & arguments to spawn for this analisis
 { //So the child_process doesn't behave like a child
   detached:true,    
   stdio:['ignore'],
   env:null
 }
);
//:The Analysis
DoAnalysis(ANALYSIS.child.pid);
ANALYSIS.child.unref()
var memPeak = 0;
function PIDStat(){
 pusage.stat(ANALYSIS.pid, function(err, stat) {
  if(err){ CheckError(err) }else{
   if(stat.memory > memPeak){memPeak=stat.memory;PrintStat()}
   setTimeout(PIDStat,100); pusage.unmonitor(process.pid)
  }
 })
}
//:UI (just for display)
function DoAnalysis(PID){
 var s = '═'.repeat(ANALYSIS.cmd[0].toString().length)
 ANALYSIS.pid = PID;
 UI.top = '╒═'+s+'═╕'
 UI.mid = '│ '+ANALYSIS.cmd[0]+' │'
 UI.bot = '╘═'+s+'═╛'
 console.log(UI.x);
 PIDStat()
}
function PrintStat(){
 console.clear()
 console.log('\n',UI.top,'\n',UI.mid,'PEAK MEM. :',memPeak,'\n',UI.bot)
}
function CheckError(e){
 switch(e.code){
  case "ENOENT": console.log("              [the analysis ended]\n"); break;
  default: console.log("[/!\\ error]\n",e); break
 }
}
```

Will produce the following output :

```
 ╒══════════╕ 
 │ child.js │ PEAK MEM. : 28737536 
 ╘══════════╛
              [the analysis ended]
```

This tool prevents you from adding bloat to the code of the process you actually want to benchmark, so this way you wont get different memory usage values, since your bloat/benchmarking code will also add memory usage to that process.

Comment: The code above fails on console.clear() in Node 6, it was recently added to Node API. Thanks, it works as intended. It should be mentioned that it doesn't work well on synchronously running processes, the script can miss the point where they have a peak. As for the bloating argument, I found that process.memoryUsage() that runs on every tick and was suggested in the other answer provides zero impact on CPU and RAM, so it's not a big deal.

Comment: @estus How could a call have **zero** impact on CPU? :)

Comment: @bluehipy It's negligible, not literally 0. I stand corrected, `process.memoryUsage()` gave 2-3% when monitoring on each tick and ~0% when monitoring with 10ms interval (which is totally acceptable in a situation like that)